# Sphero API differences between Sphero original and Sphero v2?

Tags: device, sphero-api

I haven't been able to locate a changelist of API differences between the two Spheros.

What are the differences between the two API versions? (I'm looking to buy one to control its motion programatically.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which SDK are you using?
Looking at [the Windows SDK](https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-Win-SDK) There only appears to be one version. The assumption is that the same API will work for both hardware revisions.